# How set object to new touchPosition

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I'm making a game in unity and I want my player set to the new touch position when I tap on the screen.

I created the Vector 2 position and stored it in touch and then debug logged it, and it shows the new position.

Oke, so I got this code working, my player is moving to touch.position. But it is also going to z-as -10, how can I keep it on zero. Because when I use vector3, it says cannot convert touch to vector 3.

```
if (Input.touchCount > 0)
    {
        Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);

        if (Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Began)
        {
            // Detect the touch and set object to new location
            player.transform.position = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(touch.position);
            Debug.Log(player.transform.position);
        }
```

Comment: `player = m_NewPosition;` is supposed to do what? you probably mean `player.transform.position = m_NewPosition;`?

Comment: store the player, so I can reuse it later.

Comment: well right before you declare `Vector2 m_NewPosition` .. that is not a `GameObject` or player but a vector

Comment: you already have the player stored in `player` so you can reuse it later .. as said if you want to set the position of that object use `player.transform.position = m_NewPosition;`

Comment: true I just looked at the scene and it moves to position x: 306.1365 z:126.7343, this is way out of the screen. How could I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your exception says

```c#
player = m_NewPosition;
```

makes no sense ... you can't store a `Vector2` value in a `GameObject` field.

As I understand you want to set the object to the position where you touched.

The problem:

> [`touch.position`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Touch-position.html) returns `The position of the touch in pixel coordinates.`

so you can not just do

```c#
player.transform.position = m_NewPosition;
```

But have to convert that screen coordinate to a coordinate in the 3D world e.g. using [ScreenToWorldPoint](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint.html)

```c#
// somehow yuo have to define how far away from the camera the object should be placed
// e.g. 1 meter
float distanceTocamera = 1;

player.transform.position = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(m_NewPosition.x, m_NewPosition.y, distanceTocamera));;
```